# Trying to eliminate second regex exec

Tags: regex

I am wondering if there is a way to declare boundaries other start of line or end of line but based on a value in the text. I am trying to optimize my code and right now I find a section in my doc and extract it based on a regular expression. Then I run that extracted section through another expression.

For simplicity my text looks like the

```
<start><doc><font>123</font></doc><doc><font>234</font></doc><doc><font>345</font></doc><doc><font>456</font></doc><end>
```

Since my `<start>` is not the start but somewhere in doc I have to find that. I assume if its possible it should be more effective then running two expr exec's to get the data. Anything small will help as my script will have to run at least one million times.

Comment: This seems like an XML structure. If you can, you should use an XML parser. If not, please provide the expected output and show us what you have tried already.

Comment: Emma, what i am looking for is a more effective way to to what i do in 2 steps so far
<start>(.*?)<end> is first step and then <doc><font>(.*?)<\/font> this is just a simple example but reflects the concept

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about the efficiency, if your data would be as simple and clean as it is printed in the question, this expression might be an start:

```
(<start>(<doc>(<font>.*?<\/font>)<\/doc>)<end>)
```

Otherwise, you might want to clean your data first, and maybe find some alternative solutions.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qH8rf1/1/)

Comment: That doesn't work as the Start and End tag is only present once so what i am looking for is either a way to establish a anchor based on a string in doc or a way to tell my pattern to only require the <start> tag at first match but not on any of the subsequent matches

Comment: I guess the way I do it is the most effective, I match and extract all txt between start and end then go and run my expression against that which works. I was just not sure if there would be more effective way